# How can I update an object value which uses a template literal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, object, template-literals

As you can see, the object obj2 is using a template literal defined in obj1. 
How can I update the object value for title in obj2 upon calling func()?

### In file1

```
let obj1 = { name: 'abc' }, 
obj2 = { title : `${obj1.name}` }
```

### In file2

```
import {obj1, obj2} from 'file1';

func();

func() {
let obj1 = _.clone(obj1), obj2 = _.clone(obj2);
obj1.name = 'Title of this Page';
console.log(obj2.title) // Still shows abc
}
```

Comment: Template literals are not live bindings..

Comment: @Keith - Wonderfully concisely put.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, the template literal was evaluated and turned into a string when the object initializer it was inside was evaluated. `obj.title` is the **result** of the template literal being evaluated (a string¹), not some kind of template object. Template literals are exactly that: A *literal notation* which is evaluated when it's encountered (just like a *string literal* is evaluated, resulting in a string, when the string literal is encountered).

Instead, you might make `title` a function you pass `name` into:

```
let obj1 = { name: 'abc' }, 
obj2 = { title : name => `${name}` }
```

You have to call it, of course, when you want the title.

---

¹ A string *in this case*, because the template literal was freestanding, not attached to a tag function.

Comment: *(Editing error. If you see ```${obj1.name}``` instead of ```${name}``` above, hit refresh.)*